# Problems parsing weird character in string

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing strings in this format:

```
$6,000↵2001 Jeep Wrangler↵Middleburg, Florida↵144K miles
```

I would like to iterate and add to my object like this:

```
var my object = {
    price: "$6,000",
    title: "Jeep Wrngler",
    location: "Middleburg, Florida",
    miles: "144k miles"
}
```

but that little carriage return is messing me up. How do I extract the above info from that one string?

Thank you

Comment: is it a real carriage return  (ascii code = 0x0x0D ) or the `↵` symbol ??

Answer (score 0):

The carriage return might be just put in by the console or other. Below regex will split by newline or carriage return, then just create your object from the output

```
const s = '$6,000↵2001 Jeep Wrangler↵Middleburg, Florida↵144K miles';
console.log(s.split(/[\n|↵]/))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the carriage return character by matching it against the regex `/n`, using `String.prototype.split`. If you're using ES6, you can easily use [array destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to the extract individual elements from the resulting array, and then assign them back to `myObject`:

```js
const data = `$6,000
2001 Jeep Wrangler
Middleburg, Florida
144K miles`;

const [price, title, loc, miles] = data.split(/\n/);
const myObject = {
    price,
    title,
    location: loc,
    miles,
}

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that:

```js
const data =  '$6,000\n2001 Jeep Wrangler\nMiddleburg, Florida\n144K miles';

const obj = ['price', 'title', 'location', 'miles',
              ...data.split(/\n/) ]
            .reduce((a,c,i,t)=>{
              if(i<4) a[c]=t[i+4]
              return a
              },{});

console.log( obj );
```